# Loop not working in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I have created a program that creates a file of the users name and then allows them to insert lines. I want to make it so that if they enter nothing (just pressing enter) it exits, but I have trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 char filename[20];
 char line[81];
 int X;
 cout<<"Welcome to a very primative word precessor"<<endl;
 cout<<"please enter a filename"<<endl;
 cin.getline(filename, 19);
 ofstream file_out(filename, ios::app);
 if (! file_out){
    cout<<"Cannot open "<<filename;
    cout<<"!!!"<<endl;
    return -1;
 }
 cout<<"File "<<filename;
 cout<<" was opened."<<endl;
     do {
  cout<<"Enter your notes here"<<endl;
  cin.getline(line, 80);
  file_out<<line<<endl;
  cout<<line<<endl;
 }
 while (! line);
 cout<<"last line"<<endl;
 file_out.close();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make you a 'dumbass'.  We all started somewhere =)

Comment: thank you for the encouragement :D

Comment: I highly recommend you change `char[20]` and `char[81]` to `std::string`. (Don't forget to `#include <string>`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just your while condition that needs to be changed:

while (strlen(line) != 0);

Comment: im only doing this for myself. Kinda a hobby for me thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you are comparing `line`:

```
do {
    cout<<"Enter your notes here"<<endl;
    cin.getline(line, 80);
    ...
}
while (! line);
      ^^^^^^^
```

`! line` is same as `line == 0`. Now `line` is the address of the char array:

```
char line[81];
```

So that comparison is always false as `line` will always evaluate to true.

You need to change it to:

```
while (! strcmp(line,""));
```

and add a

```
#include <cstring>
```

at the beginning.